# Help diagnosing constant CPU usage of phone during sleep (Battery Historian Chart)

Tags: samsung, battery, standby, wakelock, battery-history

I saw a great Battery Historian guide and decided to try it out. I noticed that last night while my phone was unplugged, the "CPU Running" bar was active the whole time when I was asleep. This should only be intermittent, not a constant black bar.

Here's the whole battery historian chart, CPU running stats at the top.

[image]
Hovering over the CPU Running bar, I can see what's causing the CPU to run:

[image]

A lot of "abort" wakelocks whatever they are.

1. **Abort: Pending Wakup Sources: dwc3-otg**
2. **Abort: Pending Wakup Sources: usb_notify**
3. There's also something called "Unknown".

I have a Galaxy S20 (exynos). I have not used any package disabler app or rooting etc.

Googling the above wakelocks brings back nothing. Just some random github code.

Compared to this other S20 user's battery historian chart, my CPU running bar should be intermittent only. https://preview.redd.it/edegbwhq1sq41.png?width=1701&format=png&auto=webp&s=b8d53673d3ca754feac8ded9da6ca408592f655c

Any android expert have an idea how to diagnose this?

edit: there's also constant "BLE Scanning" on the screenshot which is "bluetooth low energy". I have bluetooth off, nearby devices off, improve accuracy via bluetooth off.

Comment: [Wakelock tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/wakelock/info) may help

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of anywhere else I can ask this question? There's no discussion of these wakelocks on the entire internet. Do you think I'd get banned from android developer stack overflow if I asked there?

Comment: I am not conversant with [So] but as far as I know you won't get banned! Try asking that related to programming. //To really get to the root of the problem, you would need to root your device and identify source of your problem, whether it's an app Wakelock or kernel wale lock

Answer (score 0):

These two wake locks are related to the OS
and android doesn't give any control over the system wake lock without root
Some times the OS gets buggy and it will not release the wake lock.
your best bet is to reboot the phone and wait about 5 hours to see if the battery drainage is the same after the reboot. if that did not fix it then it is an OS bug that only Samsung can fix. not that I think that they will